# How to remove all characters after a certain character in BigQuery using standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a list of URLs/ Here is an example — [www.site.com/product/item1/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc](http://www.site.com/product/item1/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc)

How I can get all characters before question mark using BigQuery? Sо I want to get [www.site.com/product/item1/](http://www.site.com/product/item1/) from this string.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way I think is to use SPLIT function as in below example

```
SPLIT(url, '?')[OFFSET(0)]
```

As alternative, you can use REGEXP_EXTRACT as in below example

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'[^?]*')
```

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! The REGEXP_EXTRACT works excellent.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) function. You will have to create the regexp expression though.

Furthermore, you could use Dataflow to transform the data as another option.